# Задать имя анонимной ветке в Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, hg

По незнанию делал коммиты в анонимные ветке.

Справа представлена релизная ветка, слева - разработка:

[image: Структура]

Как задать имя анонимной ветке (преобразовать её в именованную)?

Answer (score 1):

Встать на родительский коммит "анонимной" ветки, создать новую именованную, затем заребейзить анонимную ветку на именованную.

Пусть дерево выглядит так (R1, R2 — релизная ветка; A1, A2 — ошибочные коммиты):

```
-- R1 --- R2
    \ 
     A1 --- A2
```

Что нужно сделать для помещения A1, A2 в ветку feature:

```
hg up R1
hg branch feature
hg commit -m "Create branch feature"
hg rebase -s A1 -d feature
```

Что получится (F, A1', A2' принадлежат ветке feature):

```
-- R1 --- R2
    \ 
     F --- A1' --- A2'
```